# Jquery element width vs inspect mode element width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to measure a element on my page in a loop and subtract it from the width of a containing element. However when I use `.width()` it does not return the same value I get when I inspect the element. I have tried `inner` and `outer` width as well. Even so it seems like it is not accurately getting the widths because what I am doing is taking the width of the text in a span for example the first text is wrapped in a span called `smoked pit wings` and we calculate that width, subtract it from the total width of the `h5` and we should get the width of the `dotted` element, you can see a image below demonstrating this, however the dots and numbers should line up on the right however they do not.

Any help would be great

Here is my code so far

```
var colWidth = $(".food-menu__column").width();
var array = [];

$('.food-menu__item').each(function(i, obj) {
    var width = $(obj).width();    
    array.push(width);      
});

console.log(colWidth);
console.log(array);  

$('.dotted').each(function(i, obj) {
    var widthDotted = colWidth - array[i];
   $(obj).width(widthDotted);  
   console.log(widthDotted);      
});
```

Here is a image of the layout of what the code looks like, the dotted span element needs to be the width of the container column subtracted by the width of the text on the left and then the prices and dots should match up on the left, but they are slightly off, but I don't understand why because jquery should be measuring them the same at the very least.

[image: visual layout of image]

Here is a image of the html generated

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `offsetWidth`?

Comment: You could probably do this with pure CSS and not need any JavaScript.

Comment: @epascarello if you have an idea how to do it with pure css I would prefer that.

Comment: First off - that's not an image of the HTML generated.  That's an image of the _inspector console_.  The HTML generated _can and often is_ different than the console.  Secondly, when does your script run? Is it in a document ready? Are you sure the DOM is completed rendering before you're attempting to get widths? And lastly, @epascarello is 100% correct - do this with CSS instead.

Comment: @cale_b how do I set the width of the `span.dotted` element when it needs to be different in every case, the name of the `food-menu__item` will be changing often so how would I set the `span.dotted` correctly it would break anytime the `food-menu__item` changed in the cms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use CSS with flexbox and not worry about calculating/setting widths. It could be done other ways with CSS too, but this seems to be the easier solution.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.column.left, .column.right  {
  width: auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.column.center {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column left">Pizza Pie</div>
  <div class="column center">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="column right">$11.99</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="column left">Ice</div>
  <div class="column center">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="column right">$0.99</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah flex, is there anything it can't do? :)

Comment: @cale_b I have not found a way for it to make me my coffee in the morning.

Comment: Awesome, way better than using js

Answer (score 1):

The default layout of elements is the [CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model). In that model, the default size that is returned for `width` or `height` doesn't take into account padding, borders, or margins. This is always confusing at first and is very often the reason why you will find that even though you've set the size of an element, it often winds up rendering a little larger than that value.

However, the DOM API of [`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) does.

Comment: offsetWidth give's me the exact same results

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's not perfect out of the box, but you might want to try this solution.

```css
p {
background:inherit;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 40rem;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
}
p:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: .2rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #ddd;
}
.desc {
  background: inherit;
  display: inline;
  z-index: 1;
}
.price {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 4rem;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-left: .2rem;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 2;
}
.price:after {
  content: '$';
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class='desc'>Some item</span>
  <span class='price'>Price</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span class='desc'>Some item - 2</span>
  <span class='price'>Price -2</span>
</p>
```

Comment: When I run this snipped in stack overflow, the dotted line goes beneath everything, I only want it in between the lines.

Comment: You should take a look at [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), for details on what makes up a good Stack Overflow answer. We always try to explain what the OPs issue was and also how our suggested solution solves the problem.